# With Griffon, Groovy and JavaFX with the MyBatis plugin, one service won't work, all the other do - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javafx, groovy, mybatis, griffon

The MyBatis Interface is defined as follows:

```
@TypeProviderFor(MybatisMapper)
interface DBMapper extends MybatisMapper {
    List<ReferenceItem> listReferences(String type)
    int addReferenceItem(ReferenceItem newItem)
    int saveReferenceItem(ReferenceItem item)
    int badOrders(int id)
    ReferenceItem getReferenceItem(int id, String type)
    List getBadOrders(int carId)
    List<ReportingMark> listReportingMarks()
    int addReportingMark(ReportingMark mark)
    List<ViewCar> listCarsForViewing()
    int addRRCar(RRCar)
    RRCar getRRCar(int id)
    int updateCar(RRCar)
    int addInspection(Inspection inspection)
    int addBadOrder(BadOrder badOrder)
}
```

The controller in question has the following snippet:

```
  if (name.equals("MaintenanceWindow")) {
        List<ReferenceItem> areas = dbService.getReferenceList("CAR_AREA")
        areas.each {
            view.carArea.items.add(new ObsReference(id: it.id, typeVal: it.typeName))
        }
        view.carArea.getSelectionModel().select(0)
        model.selectedCarArea.bind(view.carArea.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty())
        model.datePerformed.set(LocalDate.now())
        dbService.getBadOrders(model.carId)

        model.currentTime.set(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("kk:mm")))
        List<BOViewModel> badOrderedCars = dbService.getBadOrders(carId)
        log.debug("the list of bad ordered cars is {}", badOrderedCars)
        runInsideUI( {
            view.badOrderedCars.getItems().remove(0, view.badOrderedCars.getItems().size())
            log.debug("adding a bad ordered car {}", it)
            badOrderedCars.each {view.badOrderedCars.items.add(it)}
        })
    }
```

The first dbService reference ( dbService.getReferenceList("CAR_AREA")) runs fine, the second (dbService.getBadOrders(carId)) responds with ")
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.spw.rr.DBService.badOrderResults() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [3]"
For the life of me, I can't see the difference between the first definition and the second. Anyone have thoughts?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the MyBatis plug-in - it does not seem to create code that allows the compiler to recognize list selection methods that allow parameters. In other words, a medhod defintion of "BadOrderView getBadOrders(int carId)" works but "List<BadOrderView> getBadOrders(int carId)" does not.

Answer (score 0):

I need to remember the sequence -- define the method in the service, define what the service calls in both the Interface and the XML. I was skipping a step and didn't rememeber it.

The code in the first snippet is the interface definition. I didn't post the code from the service (dbService reference) -- that's where the method needs to be defined.